# How to replace github branch inside jenkins job scm from parameter value

Tags: jenkins, github, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a jenkins job groovy script like below. I want the Github branch to be taken from the parameter value.

Groovy Script :

```
 git_url = "git@github.deere.com:ABC/XYZ.git" jenkins_node = "master"
    freeStyleJob('myjob') {
    logRotator(numToKeep = 100)
    parameters {    stringParam("GIT_BRANCH", "master" , "master cert dev")   }
    label(jenkins_node)
    scm {
     git {
      remote { url(git_url) }
      branch($GIT_BRANCH)  
      extensions { }
         }
     }
```

Comment: try like this: ```build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("branch_name")```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put `$GIT_BRANCH` variable into single quotes so it is not get parsed by job DSL script. Paste your script to this [Job DSL playground app](http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/) and you will get an exception:

```
javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 12) No such property: $GIT_BRANCH for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.scm.GitContext
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScriptEngine(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:112)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader$_runScripts_closure1.doCall(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:59)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScripts(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:46)
    at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader$runScripts$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
```

But if you add single quotes:

```
branch('$GIT_BRANCH')
```

then you will get your job XML file generated correctly:

```
<!-- 1. myjob -->
<project>
    <actions></actions>
    <description></description>
    <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
    <properties>
        <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
            <parameterDefinitions>
                <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
                    <name>GIT_BRANCH</name>
                    <defaultValue>master</defaultValue>
                    <description>master cert dev</description>
                </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
            </parameterDefinitions>
        </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
    </properties>
    <canRoam>false</canRoam>
    <disabled>false</disabled>
    <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
    <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
    <triggers></triggers>
    <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
    <builders></builders>
    <publishers></publishers>
    <buildWrappers></buildWrappers>
    <logRotator>
        <daysToKeep>100</daysToKeep>
        <numToKeep>-1</numToKeep>
        <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
        <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
    </logRotator>
    <assignedNode>master</assignedNode>
    <scm class='hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM'>
        <userRemoteConfigs>
            <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
                <url>git@github.deere.com:ABC/XYZ.git</url>
            </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        </userRemoteConfigs>
        <branches>
            <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
                <name>$GIT_BRANCH</name>
            </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        </branches>
        <configVersion>2</configVersion>
        <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
        <gitTool>Default</gitTool>
    </scm>
</project>
```

Here is job DSL I used in the sandbox:

```
git_url = "git@github.deere.com:ABC/XYZ.git" 
jenkins_node = "master"
freeStyleJob('myjob') {
  logRotator(numToKeep = 100)
  parameters {
    stringParam("GIT_BRANCH", "master" , "master cert dev")   
  }

  label(jenkins_node)
  scm {
    git {
      remote { url(git_url) }
      branch('$GIT_BRANCH')  
      extensions { }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you run a job generated from this DSL it will ask you for GIT_BRANCH parameter and the value you pass will be used to set up the branch.

Comment: Thanks @szymon-stepniak